# Network Setting For Hosting Site On Guest VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, centos, linux-kvm

How can we use a web-server on Guest Windows VM hosted on Centos 7 KVM, I am having trouble with the network connection.

On my Router we have mentioned that any request coming to the `public-IP:80` that should be forward to Centos 7 Server. but the web-server is actually on the Windows machine which is the guest VM on the Host (Centos 7).

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't mentioned what virtualisation stack you use you should configure the guest VM to have a **bridged** network adapter.

A bridged adapter will allow the guest to bypass your host network configuration and the guest will obtain its own IP settings from your router (DHCP).

The fact you are wanting to host a server you should configure the guest to have either a static IP or reserve the guest's virtual MAC address on your router and configure a reserved IP address so that it gets the same IP each time. **Probably easier to configure a static IP within the guest OS**.